# C++ method declaration, class definition problem

Tags: c++, declaration, definition, forward-declaration

I have 2 classes: A and B. Some methods of class A need to use class B and the opposite(class B has methods that need to use class A).

So I have:

```
class A;

class B {

   method1(A a) {
   }

}

class A {

   method1(B b) {
   }

   void foo() {
   }
}
```

and everything works fine.

But when I try to call foo() of class A from B::method1 like this:

```
class B {

   method1(A a) {
      a.foo();
   }

}
```

I get as result compile errors of **forward declaration** and  **use of incomplete type**.
But why is this happening? (I have declared class A before using it?)

Comment: -1 for presenting invalid c++ code without indication. How can we know what you mean symbolical and what you mean serious?

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb - Why down vote, when the user doesn't even know the process of posting on SO ? Been a member for today only. Ask him to clarify his problem properly and then down vote if he doesn't.

Comment: @DumbCoder, no I will downvote first. Then when he fixes it, I will undo my downvote and possibly upvote it.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb - So why not point him how to correct it atleast ? Without any pointers he maybe lost, while other user tag on your down vote and down vote him further.

Comment: @John Fra: Are you sure that the code that you claim "everything works fine" actually compiles? If so, what compiler have you been using?

Comment: @DumbCoder:  I agree with @litb.  We aren't here to tell people how to post.  That's what the FAQ is for.  I don't think it's too much to ask new posters to at least do a modicum of research in to what is expected of participants before participating.  It's not complicated, and this expectation is pretty standard stuff for internet forums.  If someone chooses to put no effort in to figuring out how to post before blasting away, as @John Fra. has done here, then why should we put forth the effors to tell them what has already been said in the FAQ?

Comment: However, I do think that -2 is enough in this particular case, so I'll not pile on.

Comment: @Dumb I think i told him what's wrong with it. Putting "void" where it belongs should be within his capabilities, as proven by the other member functions he wrote. And putting semicolons where they belong should be pretty easy too. I'm not sure what you hint at. He claims that his first presented code "works". However if the first sort-of-function-definition is indeed intended to be a definition, his code is invalid. Not sure how one is supposed to answer it.

Comment: +1 to Martin v. Löwis who gave helpful guidance to the new member, instead of talking about him like he's not in the room. Oh wait, I'm doing that, too. Sorry. :)

Answer (score 6):

The compiler hasn't seen the definition of `A` at the point where you call `A::foo()`.  You can't call a method for an incomplete type - i.e. a type for which the compiler doesn't yet know the definition of.  You need to define the calling method *after* the compiler can see the definition of `class A`.

```
class A;

class B 
{
    public:
   void method1(A a);
};

class A 
{
    public:
   void method1(B b) { }

   void foo() { }
};

void B::method1(A a)
{
    a.foo();
}
```

In practice, you may want to place the definition for `B::method1()` in a separate `cpp` file, which has an `#include` for the header file containing `class A`.

Answer (score 2):

**C++ INCLUDE Rule : Use forward declaration when possible**.

- B only uses references or pointers to A. Use forward declaration then : you don't need to include . This will in turn speed a little bit the compilation.
- B derives from A or B explicitely (or implicitely) uses objects of class A. You then need to include

Source: http://www-subatech.in2p3.fr/~photons/subatech/soft/carnac/CPP-INC-1.shtml

For avoiding multiple inclusion of header files you should include a guard, to prevent the compiler from reading the definitions more that once:

```
#ifndef EMCQUEUE_HH
#define EMCQUEUE_HH
// rest of header file ...
// definition code here...
#endif
```

See [Industrial Strength C++](http://www.sannabremo.se/nyquist/industrial/) Chapter Two: Organizing the code.